# Javascript/JQuery: multidimensional array loosing scope when initialized in nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope, multidimensional-array

I must be missing something basic but I am almost suck on this query when global multidimensional array variable got overwritten when called in nested loop

code:

```
//global variable

line2 = new Array();

$.fn.gtest = function(){

var values1 =  "a,s";

    lines = values1.split(',');
    //First Loop
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    //second Loop
             for( var datavalueNo = 0; datavalueNo < 5; datavalueNo++) {
                        line2[datavalueNo] = new Array();
                        line2[datavalueNo][lineNo] = new Array();
                        line2[datavalueNo][lineNo][0] = "Test";
                        line2[datavalueNo][lineNo][1] = "1";
             }

    });

};
```

At the end of First loop the value of line2 is:
Test,1,Test,1,Test,1,Test,1,Test,1

At the end of Second loop the value of line2 is:
,Test,1,,Test,1,,Test,1,,Test,1,,Test,1

the for loop is called twice.

All the values that were populated into line2 from first time second loop ( the for loop called first time) is gone and its only left with the values from second time second loop (the same for loop called second time).

I hope I was able to make my query clear.

Comment: What is the problem ? what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: There are a few things that aren't clear in your question: What do you mean by "first iteration" and "second iteration"? (Are you running this function twice?) When you say "the value of line2 is...", how are you producing this formatting? (According to the code, `line2` is an array of arrays of arrays, so it's not clear how this relates to your example output).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am calling this function only once. within the function there are two iterations and in the second iteration my (array of arrays of arrays) is getting populated, but when the second iteration(the for loop) is called second time, the values saved from previous iteration(the for loop called first) got overwritten. The format I am producing by poping out the 'line2' variable in a simple alert() call.

Comment: It would help to see where you are logging the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your overwritten values is `line2[datavalueNo] = new Array();`

You have to check if this variable was defined before:

```
  //global variable
  var line2 = [];
  $.fn.gtest = function(){
    var values1 = "a,s",
        lines = values1.split(',');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      for(var datavalueNo = 0; datavalueNo < 5; datavalueNo++) {
        if(line2[datavalueNo] === undefined) {
           line2[datavalueNo] = [];
        }
        line2[datavalueNo].push(["Test",1]);
      }
    });
  };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgeqy/

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was also checking but looks like I was checking it wrongly:                     if( ! Object.prototype.toString.call( line2[datavalueNo] ) != '[object Array]' ) {
                        line2[datavalueNo] = new Array();
                    }